# Switching Iframes for hCaptcha - Selenium + NodeJs

Tags: node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

So the site that I am trying to use selenium has two pages but under the same URL; once you finish filling up the first register form, it will redirect you to the hCaptcha but it has the same URL, and when I try to find the element and switch the iFrame, it keeps saying it cannot find the element.

Site: `https://discord.com/register`

Code that I have tried.

```js
 .then(async function () {
            await tab.sleep(5000);
            console.log("Sleep Finished");
           
            let findCaptcha = await tab.findElement(swd.By.css('div.Class for Div > div > iframe[src*="SRC of the Iframe"]'));
            await tab.switchTo().frame(findCaptcha);

            let buttonCatpcha = tab.findElement(swd.By.id("checkbox"));
            return buttonCatpcha;

          })
```

Here is the HTML code in the inspect element site: https://pastebin.com/qMWuAfKW